# how to load dynamically content on primefaces carousel by clicking previous and next buttons

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces

on primefaces 3.3 there is this component called carousel. 
their example shows that they have all the data loaded from a constructor on from the  backing bean all at once. this is good if you have small amount of content

obviously if I have let say 3000 items to display, it will dump all of it to the browser making it too hard for the server and even for the client to navigate.

what I would like to do is. when the user click previous or next button of carousel, I would like dynamically in some sort of ajax pass the index of the the last content that and fetch new one, let say if it was visible from 1 to 5, and the user pressed the next button on the backing bean send the 5, so I can fetch 6 t0 10. 
how can I can do that, 
is this feature can be actually accomplished in jsf 2.0 and primefaces.

Comment: carousel does not support lazy loading out of the box. maybe you can implement it yourself, but it will be hell of a job. In my opinion, if you want to show 3000 items, you should use a different component (datagrid for example). also take a look at the circles at the left of the navigation arrows; there's one per item. 3000 circles won't fit there, so I don't know how will it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Damien noted, PrimeFaces' Carousel doesn't support lazy loading. However PrimeFaces' DataTable does support this and has a similar look and feel.

For an excellent example of the DataTable with lazy loading [see PrimeFaces' showcase](https://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/lazy.xhtml).

Of course you can try to modify the source of PrimeFaces since it is an open source project. But I think the DataTable alternative is easier. ;-)

Comment: page not found bruh